# ggplot2 - filling bar in bar plot with highest value

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm working on an internal R package for my team of epi's. My task is to simplify making a bar plot where we want to only fill the bar with the highest value. I've worked out a few functions that work fine, but I always like the challenge of condensing code either further.

Here's what I have currently:

```
library(ggplot2)

highlight_max <- function(col){
  if(!inherits(col, c("numeric","integer"))){
    stop("Input data not a number/integer.")
  }
  out = rank(-col) %in% 1
  return(out)
}

scale_fill_highlight <- function(pal = NULL){
  highlight_combos = list(
    `London Pink` = c("FALSE"="#cccccc","TRUE"="#9E0059"),
    Mustard = c("FALSE"="#cccccc","TRUE"="#DCA000"),
    Blue = c("FALSE"="#cccccc","TRUE"="#00577D")
  )
  discrete_scale("fill", "cd", palette = colorRampPalette(highlight_combos[[pal]]))
}

df <- data.frame(
  locations = letters[1:5],
  scores = c(89,62,74,88,89.5)
  )

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = locations, y = scores, fill = highlight_max(scores), label = scores)) +
  geom_col() +
  theme_classic() +
  scale_fill_highlight(pal = "London Pink") +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0), limits = c(0,100))
```

What I ultimately want to do is condense both into one function, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to pass the data/aes mappings from ggplot() into a unified function. Yes I'm aware of library gghighlight, but I'd like to figure it out on my own.

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = locations, y = scores, fill = scores)) +
  geom_col() +
  theme_classic() +
  highlight_max_value(pal = "London Pink", highlight = scores)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way of adding multiple layers or scales to a ggplot is to add a `list` object. For example, we can get most of what you want to do with a simple wrapper function:

```
highlight_max_value <- function(pal, highlight) {
  highlight <- enquo(highlight)
  list(
    aes(fill = highlight_max({{highlight}})),
    scale_fill_highlight(pal)
  )
}
```

Which we can use as:

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = locations, y = scores)) +
  geom_col() +
  theme_classic() +
  highlight_max_value(pal = "London Pink", highlight = scores)
```

[image]